# How to fix "syntax error: unexpected identifier" on module import statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

Receiving error when importing a module:

`import LobbyQueue from "./LobbyQueue";`

The error is at "LobbyQueue".

here is LobbyQueue.js:

```
class LobbyQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.players = [];
  }
  enqueue(element) {
    this.players.push(element);
  }
  dequeue() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      return "Wait List Empty";
    }
    return this.players.shift();
  }
  first() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      return "Wait List empty";
    }
    return this.players[0];
  }
  isEmpty() {
    return this.players.length == 0;
  }
  getAll() {
    return this.players;
  }
}
export default LobbyQueue;
```

imported in index.js as:

`import LobbyQueue from "./LobbyQueue";`

index.js and LobbyQueue.js are in the same directory

LobbyQueue isn't being recognized for some reason

Comment: Are you importing the scripts as modules? *edit* oh wait it's Node, nvm

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: ah. I read about that flag. also read something that said commonJS changes es6 `export default SomeClass` to module syntax `module.export = SomeClass` and `import SomeClass` to `require(."/SomeClass")`. changed the import to a `require()` and the `export default` too `module.export =...`...along with other changes mentioned in the link by @zerkms